# Eclipse does not start correctly

Tags: eclipse

So Eclipse was working windows installed some updates and restarted my computer then suddenly eclipse was not working. I have done some playing around with it and my java class path is correct I believe but eclipse will still only show the splash screen then immediately close.

Unless I run it with the -debug -consoleLog tags then it seems to work fine. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:

So when I launch it with the debug consoleLog tag the log says this

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.la
uncher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0.v
201106131736\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.l
auncher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502\eclipse_1406.dll
-startup C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.
2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-debug
-consoleLog
-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.la
uncher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
Install location:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v2011061
3.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
    eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.7.0.v2011061
3.jar
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/c:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/plugins/javax.transaction_1.1.1.v201105
210645.jar
Splash location:
    C:\eclipse-jboss-tools\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0.v20110613
1736\splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/C:/eclipse-jboss-tools/eclipse/.options not found
Time to load bundles: 0
Starting application: 1733
!SESSION 2012-08-09 13:41:59.369 -----------------------------------------------

eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.6.0_30
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.
package.jee.product -debug -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-08-09 13:42:11.367
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refr
eshing workspace to recover changes.
Application Started: 21299

!ENTRY edu.hawaii.ics.csdl.jupiter 1 0 2012-08-09 13:42:20.933
!MESSAGE Jupiter Review Plugin is up.
13:42:22.135 [Worker-5] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.i.nexus.NexusIndexManager - Updating ind
ex for repository: central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
13:42:22.198 [Worker-5] DEBUG c.n.http.client.RequestBuilderBase - setUrl hasn't
 been invoked. Using http://localhost
13:42:22.432 [Worker-5] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvider -
Non cached request
DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
GET /maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties HTTP/1.1
Host: repo1.maven.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: m2e/3.7.0.v20110613/1.0.200.20111228-1245

using Channel
[id: 0x003293ae, /172.24.143.141:65508 => repo1.maven.org/93.184.215.223:80]

13:42:22.463 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvid
er -

Request DefaultHttpRequest(chunked: false)
GET /maven2/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties HTTP/1.1
Host: repo1.maven.org
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: m2e/3.7.0.v20110613/1.0.200.20111228-1245

Response DefaultHttpResponse(chunked: false)
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Via: 1.1 204.124.139.27 (McAfee Web Gateway 7.1.0.4.0.11515)
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2012 17:42:22 GMT
Server: ECAcc (dca/536B)
X-Cache: HIT, MISS from 204.124.139.27
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Sun, 15 Jul 2012 10:54:57 GMT
Content-Length: 1130

13:42:22.463 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG c.n.h.c.p.n.NettyAsyncHttpProvid
er - Adding uri: http://repo1.maven.org:80 for channel [id: 0x003293ae, /172.24.
143.141:65508 => repo1.maven.org/93.184.215.223:80]
13:42:28.303 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Building project
pos_stub
13:42:28.334 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Reading Mave
n project: C:\epcdev\workspaces\fif_frontend\pos_stub\pom.xml
13:42:28.678 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.internal.embedder.MavenImpl - Read Maven p
roject: C:\epcdev\workspaces\fif_frontend\pos_stub\pom.xml in 344 ms
13:42:28.709 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Build participants for MavenProject: com.advancestores.storechannel.stubs:local
PosStub:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ C:\epcdev\workspaces\fif_frontend\pos_stub\pom.xml
13:42:28.818 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.7.1:generate (e
xecution: schema1-generate, phase: generate-sources)
13:42:28.818 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resou
rces (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
13:42:28.818 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: execute
13:42:29.177 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compil
e (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)
13:42:29.177 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.177 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator
13:42:29.177 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.JavaProjectCo
nfigurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.webfragment.configurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WebFragmentProje
ctConfigurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.utility.configurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.UtilityProjectCo
nfigurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.java.unsupportedDependencyTypeConfigurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.UnsupportedDepen
dencyTypeProjectConfigurator
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testR
esources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
13:42:29.209 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: execute
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCo
mpile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.javaConfigurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.JavaProjectCo
nfigurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.webfragment.configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WebFragmentProje
ctConfigurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.utility.configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.UtilityProjectCo
nfigurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.java.unsupportedDependencyTypeConfigurator
13:42:29.224 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.UnsupportedDepen
dencyTypeProjectConfigurator
13:42:29.240 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (
execution: default-test, phase: test)
13:42:29.240 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (executio
n: default-ejb, phase: package)
13:42:29.240 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.240 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.configurator
13:42:29.240 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.WTPProjectConfig
urator
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
    Action: configurator
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.configuration.wtp
.ejbmanifest.configurator
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Project configurator: org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.mavenarchiver.Ej
bMavenArchiverConfigurator
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
        Build participant: org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.Abstr
actMavenArchiverConfigurator$1
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (execu
tion: default, phase: verify)
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install
 (execution: default-install, phase: install)
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.p.c.AbstractCustomizableLifecycleMapping -
 Mojo execution key: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (ex
ecution: default-deploy, phase: deploy)
13:42:29.271 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Executing build p
articipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipa
nt for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:re
sources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
13:42:30.489 [Worker-0] WARN  o.e.m.c.i.embedder.EclipseLogger - Using platform
encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform de
pendent!
13:42:30.489 [Worker-0] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.embedder.EclipseLogger - Copying 17 reso
urces
13:42:30.749 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Finished executin
g build participant org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuild
Participant for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
:2.4.3:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources) in 147
8 ms
13:42:30.749 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Executing build p
articipant org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipa
nt for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:te
stResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-resources)
13:42:30.751 [Worker-0] WARN  o.e.m.c.i.embedder.EclipseLogger - Using platform
encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform de
pendent!
13:42:30.754 [Worker-0] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.embedder.EclipseLogger - Copying 0 resou
rce
13:42:30.754 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Finished executin
g build participant org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuild
Participant for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
:2.4.3:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-reso
urces) in 4 ms
13:42:30.755 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Executing build p
articipant org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchiverConfigur
ator$1 for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin:2.3:ejb (e
xecution: default-ejb, phase: package)
13:42:31.880 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Finished executin
g build participant org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.internal.AbstractMavenArchive
rConfigurator$1 for plugin execution org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ejb-plugin:2
.3:ejb (execution: default-ejb, phase: package) in 1123 ms
13:42:31.880 [Worker-0] DEBUG o.e.m.c.i.builder.MavenBuilder - Built project pos
_stub in 3577 ms
13:42:32.118 [Worker-5] INFO  o.e.m.c.i.i.nexus.NexusIndexManager - Updated inde
x for repository: central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 in 9983 ms
```

And here is my eclipse.ini

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true

SOLVED:

So I figured it out eventually. At some point java.exe was put into my Windows folder which was also in my %PATH% variable. Once I deleted these I was pretty much home free.

Here is more information incase someone else has a similar problem: http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Explain more about what is happening please.

Comment: Also, post the contents of your `eclipse.ini` file. Have you directed Eclipse which JVM to use, as described in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini ?

Comment: This is why you should never update a working Eclipse environment.  Create a new Eclipse environment.

Comment: I didn't touch my eclipse environment. My computer shut off and informed me it was installing updates I turned it back on and nothing worked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out eventually. At some point java.exe was put into my Windows folder which was also in my %PATH% variable. Once I deleted these I was pretty much home free.

Here is more information incase someone else has a similar problem: http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/

Comment: The same happened to me. Did you figure out what caused the 3 java files to be put inside the Windows folder? In my case, they were put inside C:\Windows\System32.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your workspace's .metadata directory and delete the .log file.  Run Eclipse again (it will still fail) and look at the .log file for clues about what happened.  You will most likely see some stack tracks from some serious exceptions.  The ones at the top of the file are the ones most likely to give you the best idea of what happened.  That's why you delete the .log file when you're tracking down problems like this.

Comment: I am not making it that far it just shows the splash screen and instantly closes

Comment: I meant that you should delete the .log file outside of Eclipse.  Open Windows Explorer and navigate to the root directory for your workspace.  You should see a directory named .metadata there and the .log file is inside that directory.  Do this before you run Eclipse.

Comment: I know. It does not log anything.